# reading values from textboxes in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, textbox

I want to read the values of my entire gridview for my project in ASP.NET.
I've been experimenting and searching for quite some time now, and haven't found what I'm looking for.

This is my gridview in the aspx page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewNatuur" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Naam" HeaderText="Mana" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Aantal">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="Number" AutoPostBack="False" MaxLength="100" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

It gets values for 6 rows when the page loads. For each of these rows, a textbox will be created. However, all of these textboxes will have the same Id, which is bad. How can I prevent this? Or alternatively, how can I read every row's textbox value?

```
BLNatuur blnatuur = new BLNatuur();
        List<Natuur> naturen = blnatuur.GetNaturen();
        BLManaCost blmanacost = new BLManaCost();
        int i = 0;
        int aantal;

        foreach (GridViewRow gridRow in GridViewNatuur.Rows)
        {
            ManaCost manaCost = new ManaCost();
            manaCost.KaartId = kaartInsertId;
            manaCost.TypeId = naturen[i].ID;
            string opgehaaldAantal = ((TextBox)GridViewNatuur.Rows[gridRow.RowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
            bool correct = Int32.TryParse(opgehaaldAantal, out aantal);
            if (!correct)
            {
                aantal = 0;
            }
            manaCost.Aantal = aantal;
            i++;
            blmanacost.InsertManaCost(manaCost);
        }
```

In the code I pasted here, the variable I want to get the part of string opgehaaldAantal right.

Please note that I'm not experienced in ASP.NET as of yet.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Just change from

```
 string opgehaaldAantal = ((TextBox)GridViewNatuur.Rows[gridRow.RowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
```

to

```
 string opgehaaldAantal = ((TextBox)gridRow .FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the values of all the textboxes, create an OnRowDataBound event that reads each TextBox as it is created and adds the Text value to a List or similar collection.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
First of all, I ran into the problem where I couldn't read the value of the numeric text box while it was still numeric. So I converted it to a SingleLine textbox in the backend.

I also found that the TextBox control was located in the second spot of the control array of the cell. (The first being the cell itself). So I had to read that array spot to get the TextBox.

```
BLNatuur blnatuur = new BLNatuur();
        List<Natuur> naturen = blnatuur.GetNaturen();
        BLManaCost blmanacost = new BLManaCost();
        int i = 0;
        int aantal;

        foreach (GridViewRow gridRow in GridViewNatuur.Rows)
        {
            ManaCost manaCost = new ManaCost();
            manaCost.KaartId = kaartInsertId;
            manaCost.TypeId = naturen[i].ID;

            TextBox textbox = (TextBox)gridRow.Cells[1].Controls[1];
            textbox.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
            String opgehaaldAantal = textbox.Text;

            bool correct = Int32.TryParse(opgehaaldAantal, out aantal);
            if (!correct)
            {
                aantal = 0;
            }
            manaCost.Aantal = aantal;
            i++;
            blmanacost.InsertManaCost(manaCost);  
        }
```

I'd like to thank the people who looked into it and helped me figure out the problem.